# Hide and Show a dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

i'm doing this drop down menu that when "aulas" is hover a submenu appears. The problem is: I can't choose the link i want on the submenu because it desappears when aulas is not hover. Please, thank you so much.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>

ul {
background-color: black;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 6px;
width: 960px;
}
ul li {
display: inline;
font-family: thinn;
font-size: 25px;
margin: 20px;
position: relative;
left: -2px;}

ul li:hover {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;

}
ul li ul li { 
  background: grey; 
  display: block; 
}
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  position: absolute;
  left: -30px;
  width: 120px;
}
li.submenu{
font-size: 12pt;
width: 100px;
position: relative;
left: -10px;
background-color: black;
top: -10px;
}
a{
color: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul><li>Home</li>
  <li>Sobre</li>
  <li>
    Aulas
    <ul>
      <li class="submenu"><a href="">Quimica organica</a></li>
      <li class="submenu"><a href="">Oxigenada</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Videos</li>
  <li>Downloads</li>
  <li>Contato</li>
</ul>
</body>`
```

Comment: It works (on firefox) or I don't understand your problem ;)

Comment: It's work great, look it http://jsfiddle.net/1fjqrdLx/

Comment: When i put the cursor on "aulas" the submenu appears. But when i try to click on a link the submenu it disappears. (probably because "aulas" isn't hover anymore) thank you.

Comment: It doesn't work in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the below rule, adjust top to 26px.

```
ul li ul {
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 26px;
left: 0;
width: 150px;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
display: none;
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
}
```